# Quartz Scheduler (.Net) - Why is the job fired immediately after built-in 'RescheduleJob' method is run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

When I run a job using Quartz I log the details to a table in my database, and I can see that when I run a job manually, or have scheduled a job, the table gets populated with the job details at the correct time.

However, when I reschedule a job using the built-in `RescheduleJob` method, the job is fired twice; once when I run the method, and then correctly, at the time the job was rescheduled to.

**Example:**

Rescheduled Job to **09:01:11**, but the job was inserted into the database twice, at:

**09:00:23** (seconds after calling `RescheduleJob` method)

**09:01:11** (the rescheduled time)

I've looked through my code and there's nothing calling the job before getting to the `RescheduleJob` method.

```
public void RescheduleTrigger(TriggerKey key, string cronexpression)
{
 var trigger = this.GetTrigger(key);
 var triggerBuilder = trigger.GetTriggerBuilder();
 ITrigger newTrigger = triggerBuilder.WithCronSchedule(cronexpression).Build();

 this.scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.Key, newTrigger);
}
```

I've Googled around and I've only found one similar case and it was unresolved. Has anyone encountered this before and can help me work around it?

Comment: I removed the `quartz-scheduler`-tag since this is just about the c#-port

Comment: Added it back in, as both have the same method/functionality.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm getting "bugs" reported by my users because of this :( 
It happens on one .NET Framework 4.6 project but not the .NET Core project. They're using different versions of quartz, but I still haven't seen anything call out that it's an issue which has been fixed.

Comment: Hey @Dinerdo I never found a solution for this. It didn't make sense as I debugged my code and the method definitely only got called once. I'm wondering if it would be worth contacting the developers of Quartz.Net. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: No problem. The first answer (for the java situation) fixed it for me. I didn't do the pause/resume steps, but I added a .StartNow() to the triggerbuilder chain and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

my case in java, have a same situation, but i work around with modifying trigger start time as now
background:
my trigger doesn`t set trigger end time, only set trigger start time, after reschedule, i found out the problem will happen when you reset the time between trigger start time and current system time e.g trigger start time 2016/03/04 10:58 am and current system time 2016/03/04 11:05 am and you set cron expression 0 59 10 * * ?, the next fire time will be set at 2016/03/05 10:59 and fire the job immediately.
After i reset start time before perform "reschedule", problem temporary solved

```
scheduler.pauseAll();
Date currentDate=new Date();
trigger.setStartTime(currentDate);
scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getName(), trigger.getGroup(), trigger);
scheduler.resumeAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unscheduled the job, and then scheduled it.

```
this.scheduler.UnscheduleJob(key); 

var trigger = this.GetTrigger(key);
var triggerBuilder = trigger.GetTriggerBuilder();
ITrigger newTrigger = triggerBuilder.WithCronSchedule(cronexpression).Build();

this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(newTrigger);
```

Then went back to using RescheduleJob

```
var trigger = this.GetTrigger(key);
var triggerBuilder = trigger.GetTriggerBuilder();
ITrigger newTrigger = triggerBuilder.WithCronSchedule(cronexpression).Build();

this.scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.Key, newTrigger);
```

This solved my problem temporarily, but then the issue restarted again.